# Media Browser shows no photos or albums?

Tags: finder, photos

I'm working on a new MacBook Air running the latest Mac OS (10.14.2).  It was recently setup using Migration Assistant from an older MacBook Pro; I think that machine was running 10.13.

When I attempt to use the Media Browser feature to access Photos from a file open dialog (e.g., browser upload dialog), I do not see any photos or photo albums (see image below).  I can see everything in the Photos app, which has many years worth of photos and albums.

[image: Empty Media Browser - Screen Shot]

I'm not using iCloud Photos (and have never done so with this user account):

[image: Photos iCloud settings - Screen Shot]

I've also confirmed that the Photos library is the system default:

[image: Photos General settings - Screen Shot]

The only other advice I've found from searching the web is to wait - Apple's own help page states that the first time Media Browser is used, it may take some time to populate.  However, I left it open for over an hour with no change.  I've restarted the Mac.  How can I make this work?

Comment: As a first step, try leaving the Media Browser open overnight to confirm you're definitely giving it enough time. It might take a long time, but it shouldn't take, say, 12 hours.

Comment: Safe to assume you've come across this page?- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204669

Comment: I also found this video which shows that you have to drag the folder of images into Media Browser to get it to pick them up - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRc5xilYKh0.

Comment: @sim Thanks, that apple support link is for "iCloud Photos with the Optimize Mac Storage preference enabled;" as stated above I'm not using iCloud Photos.

Comment: @daGUY Would you make your comment an answer?  While I had tried leaving it open for several hours before (without success), this time when I tried to do it, the Media Browser suddenly worked and loaded content from Photos.  I'm guessing that one of my previous attempts must have completed in the background.  In any event, I think this answer is worth accepting.