# Media Browser only shows videos and a few photos

Tags: finder, photos, pages, photos.app

I have an older MacBook Pro (13-inch, mid 2012) that I just updated from MacOS Sierra to Catalina (10.15.1) so that I could download and use Pages. I also deleted my Photos Library and created a new one, making sure to make it the system default (Preferences -> General -> "Use as System Photo Library" is selected). I like to organize my files through the Finder, so I don't copy items into the photo library ("Copy items to the Photos library" is deselected).

[image: Photo app preferences]

I imported just a couple of folders of my pictures/videos into Photos. I can see all of them just fine in the Photos app. I opened a document in the Pages app and tried to add some photos through the Media Browser but only a few photos show up. It turns out that of the 1874 photos in my Photos app, only 7 random ones appear in Media Browser, and those aren't the ones I want to use. Curiously, 236/236 videos from the Photos app also appear in Media Browser.

As for [this previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352329/media-browser-shows-no-photos-or-albums), I tried leaving the Photos app and Media Browser open overnight, but this did not result in any more photos appearing in Media Browser. I've tried rebooting the computer many times, repairing the Photos library, and rebooting again (doesn't help). Apple's advice [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204669) applies if using iCloud Photos, but I'm not. All photos are located on my computer hard disk.

[image: Not using iCloud]

Adding photos through Media Library seems like the convenient way that Apple intended me to use, *if* I could get them to appear. Help?